# Reference $scope variables from within $http request angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs and am having a hard time trying to figure out this issue.

Basically, we are using a factory to request data for our application. When the factory returns a promise, we were hoping that the data inside the returned promise that was defined in our scope, would be able to be used, but it is only returning as text on the page.

For example: We have defined $scope.name in our controller:

```
app.controller('AccountController',function($scope,Account) {
    $scope.name = 'Abby';
    $scope.news = [];
    Account.getSnapshot().success(function(data) {
        $scope.news.push(data);
    });
});
```

so the factory (getSnapshot) will return something like "Hello {{name}}" from an $http request as follows:

```
app.factory('Account',function($http) {
    return {
        getSnapshot : function() { 
            return $http.get('data.php'); 
        }
    }
});
```

Is it possible to allow the factory to access /use {{name}} from the $scope?

Comment: Pass it as an argument to `getSnapshot`? `Account.getSnapshot($scope.name).success(function(data) {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use internal Angular [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) service:

```
app.controller('AccountController', function($scope, $interpolate, Account) {
    $scope.name = 'Abby';
    $scope.news = [];
    Account.getSnapshot().success(function(data) {
        var text = $interpolate(data)($scope);
        $scope.news.push(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: This appears to be the answer! However I am working with an array on information that is returned from the json script. Each array element has a few indexes that would need to use the $interpolate function. Is this something that can be applied to an entire array?

Comment: You will have to interpolate each string separately. I don't think you can apply it to entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$q` and `promises` thanks to @dfsq's answer on my post similar to this. Works perfectly.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHokeqn96AOXK4kmWFV0?p=preview).

```
// Factory method.
app.factory('Account', function($http, $q) {

    var data;

    return {
        getSnapshot: function() {
            return data ? $q.when(data) : $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
                data = response.data;
                return data;
            })
        }
    }
});

// Controller method.
app.controller('AccountController', function($scope, Account) {
    $scope.name = 'Abby';
    $scope.news = [];
    Account.getSnapshot().then(function(data) {
        $scope.news = data;
    });
});
```